# Ruby on Railsでのブログアプリ作成について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, mysql

Ruby on Railsでブログアプリの作成をしています。

formを作成し投稿、保存、読込する基本的な動作は作成できたのですが、より内容の多い、自由度のあるブログを作成する方法がわからず教えて頂きたいです。

◾️現状
投稿フォームに
・タイトル
・画像
・本文

を記載して投稿すれば、それぞれの内容が決められたフォームに従って投稿・更新される。
※本文はテキストのみ、画像は参照&添付1枚のみ

◾️理想
・タイトル
・本文
を記載して投稿する。本文の部分は線を入れたり好きな箇所に画像を入れたり、好みのレイアウトで編集可能。

→ツイート的なブログではなく、1ページにわたる長い記事を装飾しながら投稿する
 ブログをイメージしています。

◾️考えたこと
①：htmlで記事のページを作成し、更新の際には都度デプロイする。
→記事をDB管理・第三者がログイン、投稿できないためブログアプリではなく、単なるホームページとなる。

②：formの画像添付箇所や本文記入の箇所を複数作り、cssも準備しておく。
→formを無理矢理延長しているだけのため、結局好きな箇所に好きなレイアウト配置ができない。
 また、DBのカラムが増え煩雑になりすぎる。

例えばこのstack overflowの投稿でも、DBに保存されているはずですが、質問本文は単純なテキストでなく
様々な書式で書いたり複数画像挿入できるのに、どのように1つ1つの投稿をDBに保存・管理しているかが不明です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railsは`6.0`から`ActionText`というフレームワークを導入しています。それを使うことで画像のアップロードを含むWYSIWYGエディタを短時間で作成できます。そちらを利用してみてはいかがでしょうか。

ドキュメントは[英語版](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html)と[日本語版](https://railsguides.jp/action_text_overview.html)があります。

Comment: ご回答頂き誠にありがとうございます。
その後、リッチエディタを使えばいいというところまでたどり着き
froalaEditorを導入しようとしてjQueryのエラーでハマっていました。
内部でフレームワークが導入されているのであれば、6.0にバージョンアップして、ActionTextの利用をしようと思います。ありがとうございました！